# DateTime syncing issue in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

The problem is I have 2 columns `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` in `text` data type in local sqlite and on server these two columns are of `datetimeoffset` data type.

When I insert/update any record using `MobileServiceClient` of azure, everything gets into database except these two column resulting in `NULL` values.

Similarly, if I update these column using `SQLite` connection, it updates records just fine. However, azure does not take these two columns' values on server when I sync.

Things I have tried:

- Inserting every possible format of date time in these columns, which I thought is the problem.
- Changing column's data type to match the data type on server but `MobileServiceClient` inserts default date and time which is 01/01/0001

I'm having trouble understanding how this service handles the data locally and on server.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the table on the server, it used to set those two columns up to get values automatically, not populated from the client.

The DDL for the columns looks like this:

`[createdAt] datetimeoffset(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetimeoffset](3),sysutcdatetime(),(0))),
[updatedAt] datetimeoffset(3) NULL,`

and there is a trigger for updatedAt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DbName].[TR_TableName_InsertUpdateDelete] ON [DbName].[TableName]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [DbName].[TableName] SET [DbName].[TableName].[updatedAt] = CONVERT (DATETIMEOFFSET(3), SYSUTCDATETIME())
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE INSERTED.id = [DbName].[TableName].[id]
        END
GO
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as your backend storage? Connect to your database with a tool like SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) or Visual Studio SQL Server Dev Tools, and update or recreate your table definition with the createdAt default value and updatedAt trigger.